# docker-compose doesn't work in specific directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been running a dev-setup for a while without issue. I'm using Docker for Windows with Windows Subsystem for Linux 2. It's been working very well. Today when trying to spin up docker-compose, it failed with the following error:

```
frederik@desktop:~/projects/caselab$ docker-compose -f docker-test.yml up
Recreating f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_caselab_db_1 ...
Recreating f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_caselab_db_1 ... error

ERROR: for f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_f26a365c8a83_caselab_db_1  Cannot create container for service db: mkdir 07ff2055c618dedc240ca3275de3f8c41d091136dc659cf463ee9fc62eed1853: permission denied

ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: mkdir 07ff2055c618dedc240ca3275de3f8c41d091136dc659cf463ee9fc62eed1853: permission denied
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
frederik@desktop:~/projects/caselab$
```

I shaved the contents of `docker-test.yml` down to simply:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    logging:
      driver: none
```

I tried running `docker run postgres` which worked without issue. I then tried copying all the contents of my folder to another folder. Now, running `docker-compose -f docker-test.yml` works without issues.

I think it's somehow related to permissions, though I can see no difference in permissions between the original folder and the new one.

As I do most of my editing in Visual Studio Code, running in Windows I'm thinking it may be related to the Windows / Linux boundary, though I'm not completely sure how. And - again - this setup has been running for months without issue so I'm at a loss for what I could have changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're not using `git` make sure you do, can you run it with `verbose` like this `docker-compose -v up`

Comment: I am using git. Nothing in my repo changed from being able to run everything to not being able to. Also, the same code works if it copy it to another folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

I noticed that running `docker-compose up` prepended a hash to the image name every single time the command was run. This resulted in a comically long image name.

Running `docker-compose images` showed this image being present.

Simply running `docker-compose rm` removed the image, which allowed the right image to be created and run.

I have filed this as a bug in docker-compose.